# python @property doesn't recognize underscored property

Tags: python-3.x, properties

I have the following class in Python:

```
class Zones(implements(DataLoader)): 
    def __init__(self, loader: GoogleCsvHandler):
        self._data = self._load_data()
        self._loader = loader
        
    @property
    def data(self) -> typing.OrderedDict:
        return self._data
    
    @property
    def loader(self) -> GoogleCsvHandler:
        return self._loader
        
    def _load_data(self):
        data = self.loader.load()
        
        return data
        
    def get_dataframe(self) -> pd.DataFrame:
        return pd.DataFrame()
    
    def validate(self) -> bool:
        return True
```

The problem is that I am getting the following error when attempting to instantiate it: `AttributeError: 'Zones' object has no attribute '_loader'`.

I can't tell why python can identify `self._data`, but can't recognize `self._loader`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to load the data before setting the loader. Change the order in `__init__()`:

```py
class Zones(implements(DataLoader)): 
    def __init__(self, loader: GoogleCsvHandler):
        self._loader = loader
        self._data = self._load_data()
```